# Error al agregar refrerencia de servicio WCF

Tags: wcf, referencias

Buenas tardes tengo un servicio web WCF en una solución distinta del cliente, osea para agregar la misma lo hago por url gracias a que tengo configurado el config asi:

```html
        <endpoint address ="basic"
                  binding ="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract = "Wcf.IService">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1:3000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
```

ejecuto el proyecto y tomo la url http://127.0.0.1:3000 en el proyecto cliente en el cual quiero agregar la referencia y lo hago usandola (en nombre de referencia le pongo proxy).
Lo que me sucede es que me queda mal el archivo Reference.cs no compilando y pongo solo una parte del mismo el error que sale es:
Error   CS0426  El nombre de tipo 'proxy' no existe en el tipo 'Cliente'

````
// CODEGEN: Se está generando un contrato de mensaje, ya que el nombre de elemento QueCarpetasMirarResult del espacio de nombres http://tempuri.org/ no está marcado para aceptar valores nil.
       [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMXNFilesWS/QueCarpetasMirar", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMXNFilesWS/QueCarpetasMirarResponse")]
MXNServicioCarpeta.proxy.QueCarpetasMirarResponse QueCarpetasMirar(MXNServicioCarpeta.*proxy*.QueCarpetasMirarRequest request);```

y luego:
Error   CS0538  'MXNServicioCarpeta.proxy.IMXNFilesWS' en la declaración explícita de la interfaz no es una interfaz en esta parte del reference.cs

```[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
       MXNServicioCarpeta.proxy.QueCarpetasMirarResponse MXNServicioCarpeta.proxy.IMXNFilesWS.QueCarpetasMirar(MXNServicioCarpeta.proxy.QueCarpetasMirarRequest request) {
           return base.Channel.QueCarpetasMirar(request);
       }```
````

Comment: Podes colocar con config entero, de <system.serviceModel> y lo tenes levantado en un IIS local? si lo ves por url esta activo?

Answer (score -1):

En WCF, cuando estás hosting un service, la información de la configuración dentro del webConfig debe ser muy explícita y clara, y sigue un estándar. Todo lo referente a WCF, tanto en el cliente como en el host debe ir dentro del tag system.serviceModel. Ya que estás hosting, deberás tener el tag service. Necitarás uno por cada servicio que estés sirviendo. Suponiendo que tu servicio se llama MXNServicioCarpeta

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name ="MXNServicioCarpeta">
            <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:3000"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="IMXNFilesWS"
                      />
    </services>
</system.servicesModel>
```

Para WCF, lo más importante de la configuración del servicio son tres propiedades conocidas como el A-B-C de WCF: **adress, binding y contract.**

La propiedad **address** es la dirección o URL donde el cliente apuntará. En tu configuración tienes "basic", que puede ser la raíz de tu problema. Ahí deberá ir la url **que utilizarás en el cliente como referencia**. El **binding** define el mecanismo de transporte/ medio de comunicación. En tu caso, imagino que estarás utilizando http (o tu cliente estará realizando las peticiones a través de ese protocolo). Entonces tu binding será:

```
basicHttpBinding
```

El **contract** debe ser el tipo completamente nombrado/calificado (**fully qualified type**) del service contract cuyas operaciones vas a exponer. Es, básicamente, **la interfaz que es implementada por tu servicio** que está decorado con los atributos:

```
[ServiceContract]
```

y sus métodos con

```
[OperationContract]
```

Intenta reparar tu configuración y nos dices cómo te fue.

Comment: Si van a votar negativamente una respuesta, por favor, expliquen por qué. Así puedo mejorar las demás.

Comment: El código en la pregunta no esta completo y supusiste que el error es ese. Deberías haber pedido todo el código y esperar para ver el problema. Muchos usuarios que hacen preguntas después no miran o responden los comentarios para mejorar la calidad de su pregunta y poder realizar una respuesta.